# XPath for HTML table cell contents starting from given contents

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, html-parsing

This is the HTML in tabular format:

```
<tr><td style="width: 150px;">Development Name:</td><td><b>Bellewoods</b></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 150px;">Property Type:</td><td><b>Executive Condominium</b></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 150px;">Developer:</td><td><b>Qingjian Realty (Woodlands) Pte Ltd</b></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 150px;">Tenure:</td><td><b>99-year Leasehold</b></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 150px;"># of Floors:</td><td><b>30</b></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 150px;"># of Units:</td><td><b>561</b></td></tr>
```

I want to extract these columns in csv binary :

```
Development Name,
Property Type,
Developer,
Tenure,
Floors,
Units
```

I am using this XPath, but its not working:

```
'//tr//td[@style="width: 150px;" and text()="Development Name:"]//td//b'
```

Comment: Use firebug to inspect.Provide a link here in comment

Comment: For example from this - <tr><td style="width: 150px;">Development Name:</td><td><b>Bellewoods</b></td></tr>

How would i extract Bellewoods, Please note its important for me that it should from Development Name ?

Comment: for that bare thing.
html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b

Comment: its not possible working, In this case i have 3200 links, & i am looking to extract these fields of information from each links.

Development Name,
Property Type,
Developer, 
Tenure, 
Floors, 
Units

If i follow node value method i will get wrong data , So therefore it is important for me that <tr> </tr> that contains 2 <td> </td> If first <td> element hold text value - Development Name:, then the output should be next <td> value = Bellewoods inside the same <tr> element

Comment: http://www.qutoric.com/xslt/analyser/xpathtool.html.Use this online tool

Comment: Thanks Ajay for the Link

Comment: .//*[@id='homeleft']/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the first `td`'s text and get the [following `td` sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//tr/td[. = "Development Name:"]/following-sibling::td/b/text()
```